# How to update PHP and MySQL in SUSE LINUX Release 11.2

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, opensuse, phpmyadmin

I have in a server SUSE LINUX Release 11.2, with PHP Version 5.2.17 and phpMyAdmin  3.3.9, How can I do for update the two elements, I tried with:

```
sudo apt-get update php5
```

but dont works, says:

```
 sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I think this is only for Ubuntu, I has been searching for the correct comands without successful.

One question, in the update I will lost the prev config?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: first your distro is very old version indeed.  13.1 is available.  Second **zypper dup**  Upgrade to 13.1 and everything will be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://software.opensuse.org/131/en

Download 13.1 and either burn it to a DVD or make bootable USB stick.
Boot from DVD/USB and do a upgrade install.

The upgrade will maintain your existing config files.